# Crashes in GetArrayLength jni

Tags: android, debugging, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

We are getting lots of crashes at **GetArrayLength** method in jni.The bug is not reproducible at any situation.When debugging the **GetArrayLength** is working properly.I am not able to find out the exact solution for this issue.This crash is happening in all Android version,however putting log of the crash in Android 8.

```
#00  pc 0000000000039190  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01  pc 0000000000013b41  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
#02  pc 000000000001475f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03  pc 0000000000010fdd  /system/lib/libc.so 
(__libc_android_abort+36)
#04  pc 000000000000f53c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05  pc 000000000021fc55  /system/lib/libart.so 
(_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+160)
#06  pc 00000000000a841b  /system/lib/libart.so 
(_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1322)
#07  pc 000000000022ffb5  /system/lib/libart.so
(_ZN3art6Thread9DumpStateERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPKS0_i+1724)
  #08  pc 00000000002302f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+16)
  #09  pc 000000000023944d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList10DumpLockedERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+104)
  #10  pc 000000000021f9b1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+236)
  #11  pc 000000000021fbfd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+72)
  #12  pc 00000000000a841b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1322)
  #13  pc 00000000000b2231  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL8JniAbortEPKcS1_+1060)
  #14  pc 00000000000b2789  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JniAbortFEPKcS1_z+60)
  #15  pc 00000000001c3843  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI14GetArrayLengthEP7_JNIEnvP7_jarray+634)
```

Here's the snippet of the code where is crashed is happening:

```
void report_gl_error(int code, gl_error **errors_hash, bool unrecoverable) {
    native_shim *shim = get_native_shim();
    jmethodID method = shim->env->GetMethodID(shim->type, "reportGlError", "(I)[I");
    jint error = code;
    jintArray gl_errors_arr = (jintArray)shim->env->CallObjectMethod(shim->instance, method, error);

    if (shim->env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        shim->env->ExceptionDescribe();
        shim->env->ExceptionClear();
        return;
    }

    int length = shim->env->GetArrayLength(gl_errors_arr);
    int *error_arr = (int*) shim->env->GetIntArrayElements(gl_errors_arr, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int err = (int) error_arr[i];
        gl_error *error_obj = (gl_error *)malloc(sizeof(gl_error));
        error_obj->error_code = err;
        HASH_ADD_INT(*errors_hash, error_code, error_obj);
    }
    shim->env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(gl_errors_arr, error_arr, 0);

    if (unrecoverable) {
        jmethodID method = shim->env->GetMethodID(shim->type, "logNativeError", "()V");
        shim->env->CallVoidMethod(shim->instance, method);
    }
    }
```

Edit:
get_native_shim method will basically call **get_env** method

```
static JNIEnv* get_env() {
JNIEnv* env;
static_vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
nativereturn env;
}
```

Full code can be viewed up here:

[core.c](https://github.com/gameclosure/native-core/blob/9ed8d903d92ffa6e52af32e18540bbee8defed08/core.c)

[native_shim.cpp](https://github.com/gameclosure/native-android/blob/6ccfcaf54d073b31ad424e86b55e9df9af4ea72b/TeaLeaf/jni/platform/native_shim.cpp)

Comment: Does this happen on the main thread, or on a worker thread, started from C++ ?

Comment: Basically there is a method `core_tick` which run every tick and call `glGetError` if there is then call `report_gl_error` method.

Comment: Why not checking if ```gl_errors_arr``` is null before using it ?

Comment: Post the code in `get_native_shim()`.

Comment: Added @AndrewHenle

Comment: *`get_native_shim` method will basically call get_env method*  "Basically" what it does isn't enough.  You need to post the actual code because you may have a bug there.  For example, what is `nativereturn env;`?  And if you wind up calling `AttachCurrentThread()`, where do yoiu call `DetachCurrentThread()` before you return from native code and to the JVM?  Are you also **certain** that it's save to cache the value of `static_vm` and use it from different threads?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have put up the links of relevant code that would help understood it better.